# How to remove a target with delay time

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I try to delete a target with delay time, code likes this

```
 -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

   targetsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray array] init]; 
   for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {// here _targets is NSMutableArray
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(target.boundingBox, location)) {
      [targetsToRemove addObject:target];
    }
   }

  for (CCSprite *target in targetsToRemove) {
  if (target.tag == 1) {
    [target setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"1.png"]];
    [_targets removeObject:target];
    [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
  }
  else {
    CCLOG(@"remove target immediately");
   }
  }

 }
```

If the target.tag = 1, I want to delay 0.5 to show its images, and then remove it, I try to use scheduleOnce, but it crashs, so how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to write this in Objective-C (I'm only familiar with Cocos2D-XNA which is C#), but see if this works:

Make a CCSequence, first action in the sequence is CCDelayTime with 0.5 as argument, and the second action in the sequence is CCRemoveSelf. Then just run this sequence on the target sprite.

Hope this is helpful to you. You may want to try https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ for more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
      {
       ...
       for (CCSprite *target in targetsToRemove) {
            if (target.tag == 1) {
                 [target setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"1.png"]];
                 CCDelayTime *delay =[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3.0f];
                  CCCallFunc *removeTarget = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self  selector:@selector(removeSprites:data:)data:target];

                  [target runAction:[CCSequence actionWithActions:delay, removeTarget, nil]];
        }
      }


-(void)removeSprites:(id)sender data:(CCSPrite *)sprtToDelete
   {
   if(!_targets)
       [_targets removeObject:sprtToDelete];

   [sprtToDelete removeFromParentAndCleanUp:YES];
   }
```

Here you are running two actions on each to be deleted sprite. So on first action you wait for 3 seconds  and in second action you call a method with parameter as this sprite. And in that method you clean up your sprite.

Hope this will help. LEt me know if not.